# How often do you tag in Git?

Tags: git

This might be a theoretical question or case to case basis but I am wondering how often do you tag in Git.

Here's a scenario:

I was working on a simple forum app (a rails app).

First, I set up the database and properly run it on port 3000. At this point do I tag it as `git tag -a v1.1 -m "Set up Rails db and environment"` of my app? or should I do something more to call it Version 1?

Next, I migrated the person model with its' data. At this point should I tag it again like: 
`git tag -a v1.1 -m "Added person model"` or do I need to do something more and have something more on the frontend (like a adding a forum text on the front end feature) before tagging it as a tag version?

And this can go on and on adding the little and big stuffs...

Sorry I am confuse I just want to understand how in the real world developers are using the tags properly. I basically thought that if every little things I've added on the app are tagged they are most likely like commits?

Thanks for the people who will share their thoughts.

Comment: This is a highly opinionated question. So it probably will be closed soon. That being said, I personally follow https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . Well, the model there is pretty complex, so I adapt it to the project, considering the scope and the number of programmers working on it. At the simplest, for a small projects, I use the master and dev branches maybe with the version branches and occasionally with the feature branches. One things remains though: tagging versions and tagging them consistently. The article is worth a read imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How my company does it:

V1 is "feature complete".  It does everything the program needs to do, per the spec.  (Feature creep is reserved for later versions.)

0.X, where X is the major number, is for stable builds.  It may be bug free (ha!), it may not, but it builds.

0.X.Y, where Y is the minor number, is for bug fixes, or defined biweekly releases that are not large enough for a stable build number.  (Think font changes.)

V2.X.Y and up is for feature creep, to be implemented after the client has paid for it, and approved it.

Another client wanted his numbers to be week based.  Even numbers were internal for bug testing, and odd was for consumers.  Version numbers were the year, majors were for week in the year, etc.

This is not a strict guideline, as other requirements will alter numbers.   Different platforms may require different things, which can lead to a divergence in version numbers. Pokemon GO has different version numbers for their Android and iPhone builds, as afaik, iTunes apps must be greater than 1.0

Ultimately, it is up to you to decide what you want to do.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A tag is merely a reference to a specific commit, and *can* denote whatever you want it to. There's no defined standard regarding 'when' to tag, though having said that, you typically only use tags to denote major and minor version releases (`v1.0.1`, `v2.0`, etc).

You have the commit message itself to specify exactly what happened at that particular commit, so adding annotated tags for every commit is a little redundant, as you can always rever tto an individual commit anyway.